# Analyze search topology in SharePoint farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, enterprise-search

Below is our one of internet facing SharePoint portal on 2010.

These are search statistics per day

**Total Number of Search Queries :**  1928

**Total Number of Daily Unique Visitors:** 758

**No of page views per daily :**  3334

Now I have plan to upgrade to 2013 and need to design the search topology.

With above statistics in mind, which SharePoint search topology should we go for?

Should I go with

1. Small search farm
2. Medium search farm
3. Large search farm

Our SP 2010 farm has

- 2 WFE servers
- 2 Application servers

So how should I design the new SP 2013 server topology including search topology?

Also, how can we calculate searchable items per day and second consider to above statistics ?

Comment: As @WaqasSarwar said below, check the number of search items you have in your Search Service Application

Comment: Hi How to check the Number of search items in search index?

Comment: Go to Central Admin --> Application Management --> Manage Service Applications --> Select your search service application. On this page, in System Status, the number of searchable items will be what you are looking for.

Comment: i found that number of searchable items are 2000 , what this number in search service application , could you explain it.

Comment: That is the number of items that Waqar mentioned in the post below, you are safely in a small farm configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint search design / topology  basically depend upon the number of item in the search index. as per the MSFT recommendation.

- Small Search Farm for upto 10M items
- Medium Search farm for upto 40M items
- Large Search farm for 100M.

check this:

[Plan enterprise search architecture in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn342836.aspx)

[Enterprise search architectures for SharePoint Server 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30383)